# JSTL database connection complain

Tags: java, jsp, postgresql, jstl, servlets

I'm writing exactly the same application as [here](http://danielniko.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simple-crud-using-jsp-servlet-and-mysql/), I connect to database, If I run my Dao as a java application via main method everything works fine; but If I run the application on server then I get:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:522)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:416)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.tok.dao.ClipDao.getAllClips(ClipDao.java:27)
    com.tok.controller.ClipHandler.doGet(ClipHandler.java:34)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:696)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:667)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:62)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

This error `com.tok.dao.ClipDao.getAllClips(ClipDao.java:27)` pointing to line below in my Dao:

> Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

This is how ClipDao constructor look like:

```
private Connection connection = null;

    public ClipDao() {
        connection = DbUtil.getConnection();
    }
```

### Update:

I was exporting the `.war` file of the app to tomcat's webapp directory.. so under `tomcat/libs/` directory there was no `postgresql.jar` lib. After adding the jar problem resolved.

Comment: What does DbUtil do if it can't get a connection?

Answer (score 1):

are you sure tha you aren't getting any exceptions previously? Maybe you can't find the config file so the connection object is never instantiated